# pair-wise equality of pandas dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with many rows, for illustration I'll use the following sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,1,3,3],[2,3,3,4],[4,1,3,2]],columns=['A','B','C','D'])
```

This results:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  2  1  3  3
1  2  3  3  4
2  4  1  3  2
```

I would to get a new dataframe consisted of pair-wise equality results between the original dataframe rows. 
I expect to get the following result:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  1  0
1  0  1  1  0
2  0  0  1  0
```

as: 
index 0- is row 0 vs row 1, 
index 1- is row 0 vs row 2, 
index 2- is row 1 vs row 2

A naive way to implement this would be:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0, len(df)-1): 
    for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
        new_df = new_df.append(df.iloc[i,:] == df.iloc[j,:], ignore_index=True)
```

Is there any efficient way to implement this operation?

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.DataFrame([[2,1,3,3],[2,3,3,4],[4,1,3,2]],columns=['A','B','C','D'])

combos = list(combinations(df.index, 2))

newData = {'{} v {}'.format(*combo): (df.iloc[combo[0]] == df.iloc[combo[1]]).astype(int).to_dict() for combo in combos}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(newData, orient='index')

#       A  C  B  D
#0 v 1  1  1  0  0
#0 v 2  0  1  1  0
#1 v 2  0  1  0  0
```

So it uses the unique combinations of index values paired in 2 - then builds the rows based on those criteria.

And if you wish to reuse this data use the following as it makes `df` easier to query:

```
newData = {combo: (df.iloc[combo[0]] == df.iloc[combo[1]]).astype(int).to_dict() for combo in combos}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(newData, orient='index')
#     A  C  B  D
#0 1  1  1  0  0
#  2  0  1  1  0
#1 2  0  1  0  0
```

And to get the result in accordance with your latest request use:

```
newData = [(df.iloc[combo[0]] == df.iloc[combo[1]]).astype(int).to_dict() for combo in combos]

pd.DataFrame(newData)
#   A  B  C  D
#0  1  0  1  0
#1  0  1  1  0
#2  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: Nice solution. For the index, I'd prefer simply `combo` (i.e. a `MultiIndex`), or even a tuple, versus string indices.

Comment: @jpp I agree, `MultiIndex` is a better solution, I went for this to make it look like the desired output. I'll add `MultiIndex`.

Comment: @zipa thanks!  honestly, I would like to keep the regular numeric index (I used the strings just for explanation, edited my question)

Comment: @my_user Edited per your specification.